# React Native com-myapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, casting, androidx

When running the command

`npx react-native run-android`

the build goes ok, but after the installation on my device i get the error

```
com.myapp.MainActivity cannot be casted to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

I'm running on React Native version 0.63.3

THis happened after i disinstalled my app from my phone and the reinstalled with the following command:

```
npx react-native run-android --variant TstDebug --appId AppTst --appIdSuffix "tst" --port 8084 --no-jetifier
```

I tried disinstalling it and rerunning wothout `--no-jetifier` but the error is still there.

In my gradle.properties i already added

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Any idea?